# custom binding to support Soap11WSAddressing10 causes ActionMismatch fault

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a defined wsdl to support interoperability where soap 1.1 with wsaddressing support is required. As a result I have set up my service so have configured my wcf service with a custom binding as follows.

```
 <customBinding>
  <binding name="CustomWsHttpSoap11" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"/>
    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                   useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    </httpTransport>
  </binding>
</customBinding>

<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TEST.BattleMountain.TestService"
        name="TEST.BattleMountain.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="TestMethod"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomWsHttpSoap11"
          name="TestMethod-v2-0_pttBinding" bindingNamespace="urn:test:services:201005"
          contract="ITestMethodV20_ptt" />
</service>
```

When I create a test request using SOA cleaner I get the soap fault

The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'urn:test:services:201005:TestMethod-v2-0'.

I'm not sure why this would be.  Request as follows

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:test:services:201005:TestMethod-v2-0</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <DistributionEnvelope xmlns="urn:test:ns:201005" />
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

the request you published is not the real request. there is no soap action which is actually send (use fiddler to see). so the client (soacleaner?) does not really send an action. see [here for details](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/10/dont-blindly-trust-wcf-logging.html).

Comment: Looking at the article it suggests the client SOA cleaner is lying when it tells me its passing the soap headers?  Should I forget using soa cleaner and generate my own proxy client?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SOA cleaner. Possibly there is a setting you should add there. You can ask them about it. For now try with your own client